# Memory requirement (for HDD) for Android based tablet?

Tags: storage

*Background:* I'm currently considering buying a [Acer Iconia A50x Tablet](http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/series/iconia-tab-a) device that runs the [Honeycomb OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29). The device is [available (or, well, not)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052QMP0A) in a variety of configurations (16GB / 32GB / 64 GB "HDD" and with/without 3G module). <sub>It seems the 3G version is only available with 16GB atm. and the non-3G version is available with 16 or 32GB atm.</sub>

Since I do not have experience with android devices<sup>read: I've no clue whatsoever how much a "stock install" of android needs and how much space the apps take, and whether they can be installed on SDHC card etc.</sup> I have no clue how much memory for the "HDD" is a good choice for such a device: <sub>(apart from bigger is better)</sub>

My question now is wrt. the onboard "HDD" memory: Is 16GB enough or would it be better to try and get a 32GB version or wait for the 64GB version? (After all, I can just plug in a 64GB SDHC card for additional space.)

*Wrt. to my expected usage*: I plan to use this device to surf the web, read emails and maybe a PDF or two. I do not currently plan to play any specific games. My music collection on the PC is only 6GB, and I would only use a small part of this on the device. No films to speak of.

Comment: This is honestly pretty vague, and I'm inclined to say that it's just plain subjective and/or too localized. How do you intend to use it? Do you have a lot of music/videos/pictures that you want to transfer to it? Do you plan to download a lot of graphics-intensive games? Something else altogether?

Comment: How on earth is this question *localized*?
Anyway: I'll edit with my usage.

Comment: Because it applies specifically to *you* and your usage patterns. I think you could contend that could be construed as localized unless someone gives an answer that covers every possible usage of a tablet and how much space it would require.

Comment: @eldare: OK. I understood localized as geographically only, sorry. But certainly my question can easily be answered by android tablet users whether 16GB would be way too low or 64GB would be completely unnecessary. Obviously if I want to put 40GB worth of music on the device, 16Gb is too little, but is 16GB too little if I want to put 3GB of music on the device? How much space will Android+ a handful of apps use up? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really an "it depends" answer. If you are only installing applications and streaming any media you consume, 16GB is sufficient. If you are copying media locally, 32GB should be a minimum.

By way of example, the tablet I was using on my last vacation only had 2GB used. My son's was full at 16GB with the movies and TV shows we'd copied on to last him a week and he ended up watching the same shows over and over.

Comment: Thanks! If you had a tablet and it was only using 2GB, then 16GB should be ample space for me.